# How to initialize a template class with a non constant value

Tags: c++, class, templates, non-type-template-parameter

I have a template class that needs I need to set the size of using the size of a vector. what is the best way to achieve this? below is a simplified version, I will link to the full class if you need to see it.

```
template<int maxParams>
class ParameterChangeHandler
{
public:
    inline ParameterChangeHandler()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    };

    //More Inline Methods that use maxparams and paramBitArray

protected:
    unsigned char paramBitArray[(((maxParams)+((8) - 1)) & ~((8) - 1)) / 8]
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVectorOfParameters = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    //This is OK
    //ParameterChangeHandler<10> paramChangeHandler;

    //This is what I want
    ParameterChangeHandler<myVectorOfParameters.size()> paramChangeHandler

}
```

This is for an audio application that I am building using the Wwise SDK, Here is a link to the actual class that is giving me the issue
[AkFXParameterChangeHandler](https://www.audiokinetic.com/library/2017.2.10_6745/?source=SDK&id=_ak_f_x_parameter_change_handler_8h_source.html)

Comment: This is not possible, the value of all template arguments must be known at compile time. You'll need to redesign this somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that. I am just unsure of how to go about it.

Comment: That depends. It looks like you want to have a template parameter so as to be able to use an array in your class. But why not make it a `vector` instead, and then you can initialize the size with a run-time value.

Comment: Change the array into a vector and then pass the size of the vector to the constrcutor to initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want isn't possible. Here's what you can do. Pass `myVectorOfParameters.size()` as an argument to the constructor and use `std::vector`/`std::basic_string` instead of unsigned char array so you don't need a constant expression for the size.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

class ParameterChangeHandler
{
public:
    ParameterChangeHandler(std::size_t const max_size)
      : paramBitArray(max_size) // or reserve and push_back as needed
    {
        // Do Stuff
    };

protected:
    std::vector<unsigned char> paramBitArray;
};
```